# Getting access to descriptor class

Tags: python, numpy, descriptor

I use a descriptor to enforce the use of a numpy array. This works fine, but now I want to find out whether attributes of a class are instances of `Spectrum` or not. My idea was to check the `obj.__dict__` and use `isinstance(obj, Spectrum)` however, `Spectrum.__get__` will return the array and thus `isinstance(obj, Spectrum)` will fail. Any way to solve this?

```
class Spectrum(object):
    """Class capable of containing spectral values."""

    def __init__(self, name, dtype='float64'):
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        else:
            print instance.__dict__
            return instance.__dict__[self.name]

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if not isinstance(value, np.ndarray):
            raise TypeError('Expected an ndarray')
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value

    def __delete__(self, instance):
        del instance.__dict__[self.name]

class Material(object):
    loss_factor = Spectrum(name='loss_factor', dtype='Float64')

    def __init__(self):
        self.loss_factor = np.array([1, 2, 3])

def main():
    obj = Material()
    print isinstance(obj.loss_factor, Spectrum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try get class variable and check it.

```
cls_attr = getattr(obj.__class__, 'loss_factor', None)
if isinstance(cls_attr, Spectrum):
    pass #TODO something
```

One should try to get class attribute with interesting name (I say try because class can have or not this attribute)

if You will try to get descriptor using owner class `__get__` method will be run with None as instance and following code will be run.

```
    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        if instance is None:
            return self
```

After this One will have descriptor instance attribute is descriptor and check for `isinstance` will succeed.